# How to unwrap json file in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a rather messy json file one of the pair values of which looks like this.

```
'response': '{"Results" : [{"results" : [{"id" : "2912362261001","usageLimitType":"allocation","usageLimit":"100","currentUsage":"45","remainingUsage":"55","accountValidThrough":"03-14-2020",\r"GivenName":"John","FamilyName":"Smith", "Email":[{"Address":"mizgier.agata@gmail.com","Label":"personal"}]
```

I would like to unwrap/tidy it up into the following

```
'response': "id" : "2912362261001",
"usageLimitType":"allocation",
"usageLimit":"100",
"currentUsage":"45",
"remainingUsage":"55",
"accountValidThrough":"03-14-2020",
"GivenName":"John",
"FamilyName":"Smith", 
"Email":"mizgier.agata@gmail.com"}]
```

1. Not sure how to get rid of the unnecessary 'results' thing before 'id'
2. Not sure how to get rid of '\r' before 'Given name' as I don't know what it corresponds to
3. How do I remove unnecessary 'address' and 'label' from 'Email'?

I am new to json, so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: are you using the json package?

Comment: @user1558604 yes

Comment: You may want to look into the pretty print module.

Comment: As far as I can tell this isn't JSON-specific, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is how you're storing the object, but once you've loaded it into python (using the json loads function) what you get is a dictionary that you can act on just like any other python dict.

```
object = json.dumps(raw_json)
object = object['Results'][0]
object['email'] = object['email']['address']
```

The first line converts from json to the object, the second line removes that extra "Results" parent and turns object into the subset you want, and the last line makes email just the address. You don't have to worry about the `\r` because it wasn't inside of a field and the json dumps removes it.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to add `[0]['results'][0]` to the second line, in order for the third line to work